# Add Domain User To The Site With Having Only Email Address

Tags: permissions, user, domain

I know that;

```
SPWeb.EnsureUser(string loginName);
```

can be used to add Domain Users with login name, to the site users. But i have a list with  only email addresses. How can i add these people to site users?

Is there anyway to get loginName from email address? Or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the following function,
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolveWindowsPrincipal()?

It has the following parameters:-

webAppType: Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication

inputType: System.String

scopesType: Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPPrincipalType

inputIsEmailOnlyType: System.Boolean

There are two overloads, suggest you use the SPWebApplication one.

More information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705754.aspx

You can then use the information returned as part of the SPPrincipalInfo object to get the login name to call Ensure User.

Comment: If that doesn't work. Why dont you just write code to retrieve the domain name from Active Directory using the Email address. Should be pretty simple to do.