# Unable to get the display name from People Picker control

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker

I am using the below code in my application page to get the the Display name from people picker. but it is returning as null can you please help me in this regard.

However if i use SPUSER object iam able to get the USername. Commented code in the below method.
Note: I was able to fetch the Email with out using the spuserobject.

```
for (int i = 0; i < userPicker.ResolvedEntities.Count; i++)
                {
                    PickerEntity picker = (PickerEntity)userPicker.ResolvedEntities[i];
                    //string username = picker.Description;
                    //SPUser user = mySiteWeb.EnsureUser(username);

                    //string displayname = user.Name;
                    Hashtable hstEntityData = picker.EntityData;
                    string emailID = Convert.ToString(hstEntityData["Email"]);
                    String DisplayName = Convert.ToString(hstEntityData["DisplayName"]);
                    Emailarray.Add(emailID);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly have a try with the below code to get the display name using Javascript from the client side:

```
var user = $("span.ms-entity-resolved").attr("title");
```

Here user is the variable which will have the display name in text format.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the email to resolve your SPUser object?

See this stack exchange question

[Add Domain User To The Site With Having Only Email Address](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58585/add-domain-user-to-the-site-with-having-only-email-address/58590#58590)

Comment: I want only the display name not windows domain user name.

Comment: Yep and so the code will resolve to an SPPrincipleInfo object which has the Display Name property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spprincipalinfo_members.aspx